# if in array when value null

Tags: sql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a sql command like the following:

```
DB::table('tb_angsuran_lainlain')->insert(array(
    array('id_kegiatan'=>'1','id_siswa'=>'26338','id_bulan'=>'1','nominal'=>'300000'),
    array('id_kegiatan'=>'2','id_siswa'=>'26338','id_bulan'=>'1','nominal'=>'300000'),
    array('id_kegiatan'=>'','id_siswa'=>'','id_bulan'=>'','nominal'=>''),
    ));
```

I want when the value is empty, it does not fill in the value in the table

```
array('id_kegiatan'=>'','id_siswa'=>'','id_bulan'=>'','nominal'=>''),
```

How to master ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you only want to create a row for records that has some of their values filled.

To achieve that, use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to get only those record that have some values:

```php
$records = [
    ['some' => '1', 'key' => '2'],
    ['some' => '3', 'key' => '4'],
    ['some' => '', 'key' => ''],
];

$records = array_filter($records, function ($record) {
    return count(array_filter($record));
});

DB::table('table_name')->insert($records);
```

Comment: The answer is very right sir, this is my next question, how to display the interface to be processed with the command that you explain above?

example

<Input type = "text" name = "id_kegiatan">>
<Input type = "text" name = "id_siswa"> <br>
<Input type = "text" name = "id_bulan"> <br>
<Input type = "text" name = "nominal"> <br>

How to get id_siswa and id_bulan value, while id_kegiatan and nominal value is different?

Comment: Whay error ?
Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `tb_angsuran_lainlain` (`id_bulan`, `id_kegiatan`, `id_siswa`, `nominal`) values (1, 1, 67540, 100000), (1, 1, 67540, 100000), (1, 1, 67540, 100000), (1, 1, 67540, 100000))